# How can I have the right format of time with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Hello I have this column :

```
date1
6/19/2019 3:10:12 PM
```

I wanted just to extract the time so I used the following query :

```
select try_parse([date1] as time using 'en-US') from myTable
```

But the problem is I got this :

```
15:10:12.0000000
```

whereas I would like to just have this :

```
15:10:12
```

How can I solve this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(try_parse([date1] as datetime using 'en-US'), 'HH:mm:ss') from myTable;
```

Comment: I tried but I got `Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function` :/

Comment: Why? Is the column varchar?

Comment: I do think because I use try_parse to convert the string as a time/date.

Comment: Then you can;t use `[date1]` as the 1st argument. It accepts a datetime type.

Comment: I can or I can't ?

Comment: You can't. Only if it is converted to datetime.

Comment: I tried this : `SELECT FORMAT(try_parse([date1] as time using 'en-US'), 'HH:mm:ss', 'en-US') from myTable;` but I got NULL :/

Comment: @PeterHarris . . . These functions do not exist in SQL Server 2008.  How can this be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT convert(varchar(max), try_parse('6/19/2019 3:10:12 PM' AS time USING 'en-US'), 108)
       FROM mytable;
```

if you want the result as a string for displaying purposes. (But you shouldn't store a date/time as string. Use the proper data types.)

Comment: Yes I thought to use substring but in my case I would like to keep the type of the data and therefore not use convert :/

Comment: @PeterHarris: The your question makes no sense. A `time` has no format. It only can be represented in different formats. But such a representation is a string (not necessarily a `[n][var]char` in the database, but in the program displaying it on your screen). Maybe you want to format it in the client prior display?